# MongoDB query with regex if property is null

Tags: spring, mongodb, mongorepository

I have a query to filter orders by name of client, email and phone

```
@Query(value = "{ $and: [ { 'fullName' : {$regex:?0,$options:'i'} },
                          { 'phone' : {$regex:?1,$options:'i'}},
                          { 'email' : {$regex:?2,$options:'i'}}  ] }")
Page<Order> filter(String fullName, String phone, String email, Pageable pageable);
```

It works,but only select orders where all the search fields are not null. How could I change the query to get more orders?

In SQL it would be something similiar to:

```
where (order.fullName Like queryfullName or queryfullName is null or order.fullName is null)
and (order.phone Like queryphone or queryphone is null or order.phone is null)
and (order.email Like queryemail or queryemail is null or order.email is null)
```

Comment: What are some actual values being passed through to your query? Since you are using these values as regular expressions you can alter the values instead of complicating the query. The current query also doesn't need to use `$and` : [`$and` is implicit for a compound query](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-documents/#specify-and-conditions) and only required if you need to repeat field names.

Comment: Although your question isn't specifically about performance, if  you want your queries to be efficient and take advantage of an index you should avoid using [case-insensitive `$regex`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/#index-use). I also wouldn't expect case-insensitive search to have much value for a field like `phone` unless you are storing mnemonics.